# How to stop Screen Recording in App Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscreen, rpbroadcastsamplehandler

I have one code for detected if user try to screen recorder now I want to stop recording that's mean the red part in left side is stoped

here is my code for detecting now how can I stop recording automatically or dismiss recording in isCaptured == true
I can't find any code for how to stop

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if (keyPath == "captured") {

            let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured

            if (isCaptured == true) {
///How to stop screen recording after 5 sec
                }
}
```

here is my code for creating the Screen Recorder now I want to stop this with one button

```
let broadcastPickerView = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: btnRS.frame.width, height: btnRS.frame.height))
    broadcastPickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if let button = broadcastPickerView.subviews.first as? UIButton {
        button.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.white

    }


    btnRS.addSubview(broadcastPickerView)
    broadcastPickerView.tintColor = .yellow
    broadcastPickerView.backgroundColor = .clear
    broadcastPickerView.showsMicrophoneButton = true

    btnRS.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)


}
```

Comment: add some additional code

Comment: I dont think you can stop the recording but you can update your view to hide things

Comment: @Scriptable I see in one application can stop the record

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik. mybe I will use somekode like resignFirstResponder but I don't have a any idea

Comment: check this for help: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/detecting-screen-capturing-in-ios-11-cca15881c785

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik this link stop just the timer not screen recorder

Comment: If you don't want your screen to be recorded then  you  can add  blur view to main window or white view until recording is the screen

Comment: this is not screen recorder but its relevent https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61124

Comment: @ShahbazAkram I updated my question

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I updated my question

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I need to stop

Comment: @MidDev did you find any answer ??